# Excel 2013 Web Query to an HTTPs page through Proxy

Tags: microsoft-excel, proxy, internet-explorer, microsoft-excel-2013

After countless hours spent on the Internet and various stack communities, I decided to sign up here to ask the question directly.

I'm getting a page cannot be displayed error when trying to access a webpage from within Excel 2013. It's a Web Query to an HTTPS page. No scripting, just accessing it from Data -> From Web -> Typing in the URL directly

Here are some points to note

1. I can access other URLs fine like google.com both via http and https in excel
2. The URL I'm trying to access works fine on Internet Explorer and Chrome on the same PC
3. The PC is configured with a proxy pac file which allow direct access to the URL I'm trying to access (*.example.com)
4. I get the same result if I totally bypass the proxy as well
5. The URL I'm trying to access re-directs to another URL for authentication (the first request gets a 302 Found response)
6. For some reason, Excel doesn't seem to respond to this first response from the server.
7. Interestingly, If I run Fiddler with Excel, there is no issue. It displays the page.

Any registry keys or GPO which may block Excel to respond to 302 response?

If I try the same request from IE, the first request gets a 302 Found response. IE then send in another POST request for authentication. A response with a cookie is received, then IE sends a GET request for the page and the response is the page.

Any ideas are welcome. Hope you can help.

Comment: I assume you are using the functions that retrieve the HTML from a page and such? (I don't remember off hand the exact ones but have used them before) If you are using those kinds of methods, excel only sees whatever internet explorer sees. So if you can't get to a page with IE then excel won't. If you can with IE then excel should be able to

Comment: @Scott Craner: I'm not using any functions as such. Just trying with built in functionality of Excel. I can get to the page on IE, but not on Excel.

Comment: @TGeorge that was not my comment you should direct it to EricF.

Comment: @ScottCraner: oops.. sorry. newbie mistake.

Comment: Anyone please??

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out what was wrong. Symantec Endpoint Protection was blocking certain URLs from Excel because it treated them as Ransomware.
All we had to do was to add exceptions and it started working fine.